# Adding class to all and one indexed items in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have managed to get the click function to display the specific items to add class on click.

The behavior im looking for.

1. Index both list item types because they will have the same amount of items.
2. On primary-list-item click fire 3 and 4.
3. Add class hide to **all** items but the indexed **primary-list-item** clicked.
4. Add class to the **specifically** indexed **controls-list-item** clicked.

The code submitted doesnt quite index the clicks properly.
Examples and ideas welcome & **thankyou in advance**.

```js
$('.primary-list-item').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
$('.primary-list-item').removeClass('hide');
$('.controls-list-item').removeClass('show');
$(this).removeClass("hide");
$(this).removeClass("show");
var index = $(this).index();

  $('.links-block-list').each(function() {
  $('.primary-list-item', this).not(':eq(' + index+')').addClass('hide');
  $('.controls-list-item', this).eq(index).addClass('show');
  })
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.primary-list-item {
  display: flex;
}

.controls-list-item {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="links-block-list">
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the variable `index` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, having a class `hide` and `show` gets confusing. "Show" should just be the absence of `hide` (or vice versa as you prefer).

Getting rid of that complexity makes the code much easier. You were of course missing the `index` variable which is just `$(this).index()` for the clicked item.

```js
$('.primary-list-item').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $('.links-block-list > .primary-list-item').index(this); // index of clicked item
  $('.primary-list-item').not(this).addClass("hide"); // hide all other primary items
  $('.controls-list-item').eq(index).removeClass('hide'); // unhide the same index from control list as clicked primary
});

$('#reset').click(function(){
   $('.primary-list-item').removeClass("hide");
   $('.controls-list-item').addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.primary-list-item {
  display: flex;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="links-block-list">
  <ul class="links-block-list">
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="primary-list-item"><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="controls-list-item hide"><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>

<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: I done the above and yea works the first after the second item in the list it doesnt seem to index right. even thought it works here. @Jamiec

Comment: @zen but how do you click the second item when theyre hidden? Do you have a reset button or something?

Comment: I have a reset button or i refresh page, the first click in the list works fine but then from the second it grabs the next item in the list like +1 @Jamiec

Comment: @zen see update with reset logic. Its as simple as adding/removing the `hide` class as appropriate. With refreshing the page all should work as normal.

Comment: Thats the same logic i had, but thanks so much, some reason its still not indexing right, choosing the wrong one, only works for the first click in the list. The second and third and so on choose the wrong coresponding item in the list. so annoying @Jamiec

Comment: @zen have you got more than one of these types of lists on the page? This code assumes only one, but could be scoped better to refer to the current list if need be

Comment: I have just one list with this naming. I think the issue might be is that wordpress is being used to generate two list types in one list. But i cant use two seperate ul's cause it will loop and create a ul for each li in the list. I think if i was more speific with the scoping it might work but i dunno where to start. @Jamiec

Comment: My suggestion is to copy the generated html from wordpress and try to create a [mcve] in a new question. Feel free to ping me here if you like and ill take a look.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, When i can ask more questions ill post it, I'm currently at my limit. @Jamiec

Comment: I changed the questions to have the same layout as the wordpress output, the reason why it doesnt work is because of the list item order, can this be solved? @Jamiec

Comment: @zen answer updated - yes you needed a different way of finding `index`.